# TypeError: stripe.customers.listPaymentMethods is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

When trying to list the payment methods owned by the customer from the backend server, I'm getting this error. Stripe documents have an API on the same name but it doesn't seem to work in my case. I need to fetch all the payment methods in my backend and send them back to the client side for future use.

API reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list

Code:

```
app.post("/savedCards", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  let { customerId, paymentMethodId } = req.body;
   const paymentMethods = await stripe.customers.listPaymentMethods(
   'cus_M3nQBIvz9qykuG',
   {type: 'card'});
   console.log(paymentMethods);

   res.status(200).send(paymentMethods.data[0].card);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: stripe.customers.listPaymentMethods is not a function
    at C:\Users\rekha d\OneDrive\Desktop\test_cards\card-section\server\index.js:72:51
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rekha d\OneDrive\Desktop\test_cards\card-section\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:214:15)
    at C:\Users\rekha d\OneDrive\Desktop\test_cards\card-section\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:219:13
    at optionsCallback (C:\Users\rekha d\OneDrive\Desktop\test_cards\card-section\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:199:9)     
    at corsMiddleware (C:\Users\rekha d\OneDrive\Desktop\test_cards\card-section\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:204:7)      
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rekha d\OneDrive\Desktop\test_cards\card-section\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: What version of the Stripe node library do you have?

Comment: Stripe node library: 8.131.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least [version v8.180.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/releases/tag/v8.180.0) of the Stripe Node library to list payment methods this way.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that listPaymentMethods isn't a function. It looks like per [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list?lang=node#list_payment_methods-type), it should be stripe.paymentMethods.list, rather than stripe.customers.listPaymentMethods:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
  customer: 'cus_9utnxg47pWjV1e',
  type: 'card',
});
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments below, you can upgrade to the newer version of the stripe-node library where `listPaymentMethod` is a valid method.

Comment: please go through the document properly, the second example in the document is about stripe.customers.listPaymentMethods API

Comment: There are two ways to do this list, `listPaymentMethods` is the newer one. If you're getting that error it means you are using an old version of the stripe-node library before it was added in https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#81800---2021-10-11 .

Comment: Since the error you were getting indicated it was not a function, I assumed you could not be using a version where it is in fact a function.

Comment: I had the same problem and was using this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer?lang=node